# Avoid bloating file size when removing OCRed text from a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, pdftk

I use [`pdfimages` and `convert` recommended by Anthon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171941/674) to remove the OCRed text of [a pdf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/ull.pdf), and the size of the pdf file changes from 29MB to 373MB.

My first step is split the pdf file into a pbm file per pdf page:

```
mkdir tmp1
pdfimages ull.pdf tmp1/ull
```

The total size of the generated pbm files are 788M.

In my next step, I convert and combine the generated pbm files to a pdf file

```
cd tmp1
convert ull*.pbm all.pdf
```

This goes wrong, however, because it requires more than 1 GB space on `/tmp`, and my `/tmp` doesn't have that much free space. So my second step is actually:

```
mkdir tmp2
for i in ull-*.pbm; do convert $i tmp2/$i.pdf ; done
cd tmp2
pdftk ull-???.pbm.pdf ull-????.pbm.pdf cat output ../../all.pdf
```

The generated pdf file `all.pdf` has 373MB, much larger than the original size 29MB.
I run `pdftk all.pdf output new.pdf compress`, but it doesn't reduce the file size.

Since all I want is to remove OCRed text from the pdf file, how can I avoid the file size bloating?

Comment: Have you tried setting TMPDIR to somewhere with enough space? TMPDIR is the canonical Unix environment variable that should be used to specify a temporary directory for scratch space.

Answer (score 3):

If the original image  are JPEG files, you could use `pdfimages` option `-j`. From `man pdfimages`:

```
-j     Normally, all images are written as PBM (for monochrome  images)
       or  PPM  (for  non-monochrome  images) files.  With this option,
       images in DCT format are  saved  as  JPEG  files.   All  non-DCT
       images are saved in PBM/PPM format as usual.
```

I am not sure how to control the way convert stores the images in the PDF file, but you can use `-quality` and `-resize` to alter the compression quality.

By calling `convert` in one of the following ways

```
TMPDIR=/home/tim/tmp  convert ...
MAGICK_TMPDIR=/home/tim/tmp convert ...
```

you can have convert use `/home/tim/tmp` as the temporary directory and circumvent the space problems. (Which probably has no influence on resulting file size).